# how can we capture exit code of bash script while running the bash script in python

Tags: python3

I am executing a bash script using `subprocess` module.

```
subprocess.call(['temp.sh'])
```

As per python if the `temp.sh` file is present it calls the script and it doesn't worry about the success or failure of `temp.sh`. I want to capture the exit code of `temp.sh` in order to proceed further with rest of my python script.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466711/what-is-the-return-value-of-os-system-in-python

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated. Use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Comment: And don't used `.sh` at end of files names. It is bad practice, consider what would have to change if you re-wrote the script in python.

Comment: tq for your advises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) function returns a [returncode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) object, which is an *int*.  It will be the value of the exit code of the subprocess process.

```
>>> foo = subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/true'])
>>> foo
0
>>> foo = subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/false'])
>>> foo
1
```